# My code stops at a certain condition

Tags: c++

In this code I input a test case number t and then input t numbers (n). Then my code prints the nth prime number. In the 1st line of the function, prime(), if I write `if(a > 43000) return;` Then the code works perfectly. But if I write `if(a >= 165000) return;` in the same place, codeblocks says the program has stopped working. But I can't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int p[15000];
void prime(int a, int i)
{
    if(a >= 165000) return;
    else {
        int q = 0;
        int s=sqrt(a), d=3;
        while(d<=s){
            if(a % d == 0) {
                q = 1;
            }
            d += 2;
        }
        if(q == 0) {
            p[i] = a;
            i++;
            a += 2;
            prime(a, i);
        }
        else {
            a += 2;
            prime(a, i);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    p[0]=2;
    prime(3, 1);
    int k, T;
    cin >> T;
    for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++){
        cin >> k;
        cout << p[k - 1] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you find when you ran it through a debugger?

Comment: That's a _lot_ of recursion.... Stack overflow? Try moving the recursive call to better allow TCR..

Comment: If you're going to ask other people to look at your code, the least you could do is name your variables.

Comment: Recursion.  Recursion takes up space, in a space limited area.  Can you write this as an iterative solution?  I don't think online judges care.

Comment: Since you are using C++, you should take advantage of the `bool` type with `true` and `false` and not use integers.  If your reference is using integers to represent logical conditions, throw it in the trash and get a more modern and correct reference.

Comment: The `sqrt` function take a lot of execution time.  You could change the comparison to `while ((d*d) < a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll point out that your array `p` has only 15000 elements and that the 15001-th prime number is 163,847. This means that if you do a check for `a >= 165000` before quiting you'll end up trying to fill indices of your array that are outside the bounds of your array.

Second, everyone is quite right that you should be careful when doing recursion. With each run of `prime()` you're allocating space for 5 new integer variables `a`, `i`, `q`, `s`, and `d`. This means you're allocating memory for tens of thousands of integers when (from the looks of your method) all you really need is 5.

Since it looks like these values are independent of all other iterations, you can employ a couple tricks. First, for q, s, and d by declaring them as globals they will only be allocated once. Secondly, by changing `prime(int a, int i)` to `prime(int &a, int &i)` you wont be allocating memory for `a` and `i` with each loop. This changes your code to look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int max_size = 15000 ;
int p[max_size];
int q ;
int s ;
int d ;

void prime(int &a, int &i)
{
    if (i>=max_size) return ;

    q = 0;
    s=sqrt(a) ;
    d=3;

    while(d<=s){
        if(a % d == 0) {
            q = 1;
        }
        d += 2;
    }
    if(q == 0) {
        p[i] = a;
        i++;
        a += 2;
        prime(a, i);
    }
    else {
        a += 2;
        prime(a, i);
    }

}

int main()
{
    p[0]=2;
    int a(3), i(1) ;
    prime(a, i);
    int k, T;
    cin >> T;
    for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++){
        cin >> k;
        // You should do a check of whether k is larger than
        // the size of your array, otherwise the check on p[k-1]
        // will cause a seg fault.
        if (k>max_size) {
            std::cout << "That value is too large, try a number <= " << max_size << "." << std::endl;
        } else {
            cout << p[k - 1] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A couple of other changes:

- instead of filling the array until you reach a specific prime number, I've changed your check so that it will fill the array until it hits the maximum number of entries.
- I've also included a check as to whether the user has passed an index number outside the range of the "p" array. Otherwise it will produce a segmentation fault.

Now compiling this and running gives:

```
$ g++ prime_calc.cpp -o prime_calc
$ ./prime_calc
3
1500
12553
15000
163841
15001
That value is too large, try a number <= 15000.
```

Comment: @Shajid If using global variables, I would also suggest either placing them in a namespace such as `namespace prime_detail` to minimise name pollution (or giving the variables more detailed names), or placing `prime()` in a separate source file, then making the variables file-scope instead of global.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help